# How can I generate a dynamic array in a function and reverse it in another function and return it back to screen?

Tags: c, arrays, function, dynamic-arrays

I know a bit of C++ but I need to do this in C which seems to be far more complicated. As you can probably see from my code I try to have a function that generates an array and then a different function that will reverse the order of this array. The function to generate the array is just a dummy function that will be replaced by input from a different programming language (which will be done through a function that will map the values to something recognisable in C). The reverse function, even tough I know how to do it I do not know how to pass the values from my generateArray back to main and into the reverseArray (it needs to happen in this orderI cannot call reverseArray from within the generateArray).

Also, I get an error in my code right now which says:

**reverse.c: In function ‘main’:
reverse.c:19:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   p = generateArray(m);**

**reverse.c: In function ‘generateArray’:
reverse.c:42:8: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 return a;**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//int reverseArray();
int generateArray(int size);

int main()
{

   int seed = time(NULL);
   int *p;
   int m;

   printf("please insert the size of the array:");
   scanf("%d",&m);

   p = generateArray(m);

   for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
      printf("%d \n", *(p+i));
   }


return 0;
}

   int generateArray(int size)
   {

   static int *a;

   a = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

     for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
     {
       a[i]=rand()%12+1;
     }

   return a;

   }

//int reverseArray(){}
```

Comment: What is the return type of the function `generateArray`? What is the type of the variable `a` that you want to return? Do those two types match?

Comment: Also note that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expressions `*(p+i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. I recommend you use the array-indexing syntax whenever possible.

Comment: `int generateArray(int size);` something be missing here. Where's the array?